# Php review string, update and echo updated version

Tags: php

I am looking for a way to review the contents of a PHP string, replace a key phrase if included and then echo the updated string with the replacement in place.

The below looks at the content of the `$character['text']` string and removes `PhraseToRemove` from it - but I cant manage to echo the updated version of `$character['text']`

Can anyone help me out?

```php
<?php
if (strpos($character['text'],'(PhraseToRemove)') !== false) {
    $url = str_replace('(PhraseToRemove)', '', $url);  
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't see any attempt to echo?

Comment: Like `echo $url`?

Comment: How are `$url` and `$character['text']` connected?

Comment: OK maybe my approach above is just totally wrong then...? All I want to be able to do is read the value of $character['text'] - remove 'PhraseToRemove' if included and then echo the udpated version with 'PhraseToRemove' removed if it appeared

Answer (score 0):

I think you this works for you

```php
<?php
if (strpos($character['text'],'(PhraseToRemove)') == true) {
    $url = str_replace('(PhraseToRemove)', '', $character['text']);
    echo $url;  
}
?>
```

I change `!== false` to `== true` 
And `$url = str_replace('(PhraseToRemove)', '', $url);`   to `$url = str_replace('(PhraseToRemove)', '', $character['text']);`

Comment: Many thanks - I added an else statement to render the original string if no change to remove the 'PhraseToRemove' was required - thank you

Comment: You're welcome, if my answer helped you with your question, I would appreciate it if you upvote my answer and choose it as the best answer as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to check if `PhraseToRemove` is in text. If `PhraseToRemove` is **in** text - it will be removed, otherwise - text will not be changed:

```
echo str_replace('(PhraseToRemove)', '', $character['text']);
// or
$character['text'] = str_replace('(PhraseToRemove)', '', $character['text']);
```